# `qsub` leaves "NotQueued " in "blocked jobs"

Tags: linux, bash, process, cluster, job-control

I am working on a remote cluster ([westgrid > bugaboo](https://www.westgrid.ca/support/quickstart/bugaboo)) on which I submit processes via a `.pbs` file. My `.pbs` looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l procs=1
#PBS -l walltime=100:00:00
#PBS -N SimulationName
#PBS -m ea
#PBS -M myname@gmail.com
#PBS -l pmem=3000mb
#PBS -t 1-100

echo "Starting run at: `date`"

R --vanilla --args ${PBS_ARRAYID} < /Path/To/code.R

echo "Job finished with exit code $? at: `date`"
```

, where `PBS_ARRAYID` will take the values 1 to 100 for each specific job. `/Path/To/code.R` is a R wrapper for some binary file written in `C`. When I submit the job

```
$ qsub mypbs.pbs
```

everything seems to work fine. Simulations run as expected and I got the outputs. The issue is that at some point, while the simulations are running, I often see weird jobs in the "blocked jobs".

```
$ showq -u myName

active jobs------------------------
JOBID              USERNAME      STATE PROCS   REMAINING            STARTTIME


0 active jobs            0 of 4516 processors in use by local jobs (0.00%)
                        428 of 436 nodes active      (98.17%)

eligible jobs----------------------
JOBID              USERNAME      STATE PROCS     WCLIMIT            QUEUETIME


0 eligible jobs   

blocked jobs-----------------------
JOBID              USERNAME      STATE PROCS     WCLIMIT            QUEUETIME

30004048[]          matthey  NotQueued     1  2:02:00:00  Wed Mar 23 12:56:27
30156104[]          matthey  NotQueued     1  2:02:00:00  Mon Mar 28 01:14:16

2 blocked jobs   

Total jobs:  2
```

The Job ID are indeed the same as those who run (or ran before) but these two blocked jobs do not have any `PBS_ARRAYID` in between the square brackets. These jobs stay there for a long time and I can't delete them

```
$ qdel 30004048[]

qdel: nonexistent job id: 30004048[]
```

Also, I cannot submit any new job (which is the main trouble) as I receive the message

```
$ qsub mypbs.pbs

qsub: submit error (Maximum number of jobs already in queue MSG=Job 30893576.b0 violates the global server limit of 500 jobs queued per user)
```

even though I do NOT violates this server limit. Eventually these "NotQueued" jobs end up disappearing but only after a relatively long time.

This problem has happened to me several time in the past and among all users of this cluster, I seem to be the only one experiencing this issue. When contacting the support, they usually end up somehow deleting the two jobs but so far I haven't received any long term solution to this problem.

- Do you have any idea of what is going on?
- Can I delete these two weird jobs?
- How can I avoid such things to happen again?

Answer (score 0):

“These jobs stay there for a long time” I guess/hope after two years they are finalized.
Anyway, I stumbled across the same question (“Can I delete these (…) weird [array] jobs”) and the usage of (typewriter) quotation marks (single or double) solved the problem:

```
qdel "job_identifier[]"
```

to delete the full array. Additionally you can specify a specific `$PBS_ARRAYID` (or a range) with the `-t` option

Comment: Can you provide some more context to your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your request. So I tried to answer the second question: "Can I delete these two weird jobs". And the answer is yes in the following way. Or are you confused by the following remark on the range option?